# npp_destroy gets called immediately after npp_new

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I am trying to make a NPAPI plugin for chrome on Mac. I have written a basic npapi plugin and a basic `manifest.json` and `background.html` to load it. My `background.html` has a `embed` tag to fetch the plugin by Mimetype.

Now when I load my unpackaged extension from Chrome  and try to debug the c++ code (in xcode4), I found that the functions are getting called in following order:

1. `NP_Initialize`
2. `NP_GetEntryPoints`
3. `NPP_New`
4. `NPP_Destroy`

After this when I click on the extension icon, the `popup.html` should get executed. My `popup.html` has these lines:

line 1:

```
var pluginObj = document.getElementById("pluginId");
```

line 2:

```
pluginObj.Myfunction();
```

But on line 1, `NP_Getvalue()` function doesnt get called and so a "scriptable NPObject" is not instantiated. On line 2, the Chrome JavaScript console says:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'Myfunction' TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'Myfunction'
```

Why does the `NPP_Destroy` functions gets called immediately after the `NPP_New function`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you done drawing and event model negotiation in your plugin? Starting with Chrome 22 for Mac, the long-deprecated QuickDraw and Carbon models are no longer supported, and if your plugin doesn't negotiate modern models, it will be destroyed just after init. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/diff?spec=svn11310&r=11310&format=side&path=/trunk/plugins/npapi/main.cpp) for example code that does this.

(Yes, it's unfortunate that the default models for 32-bit plugins are the old, deprecated models, but there's no way to change that in the spec due to all the existing plugins that expect the old behavior.)

Comment: Whoa! Thanks alot!! This solved my problem!! Have been trying various solutions from past few days..

Comment: If someone provides a working answer to one of your questions, you should mark it as answered; this helps people looking for unanswered questions not waste their time, and people looking for answers find the answer quickly.